# Why is the whole Yom Kippur avodah said at Musaf?

Tags: tefilla, yom-kippur, korban, musaf

Yom Kippur Musaf includes a piyut describing the avodah that the Kohen Gadol does on that day.  Why is the whole thing said at Musaf?  Wouldn't it make sense to say

- the part about the history of the world... at some point, maybe on Rosh Hashana;
- the part about 7 days before Yom Kippur 7 days before Yom Kippur;
- the part about erev Yom Kippur on erev Yom Kippur [the oath is a particularly nice connection to Kol Nidrei];
- the part about the terumas hadeshen at Maariv;
- the part about the Tamid at Shacharis;
- the next large chunk at Musaf;
- the part about the Tamid at Mincha;
- and finish it either immediately or at Neilah?

Obviously it wouldn't make too much sense to split אמיץ כח in this way.  I'm not sure about the other piyutim that are used or have been used in the past.  But that's just because of the composition; it would have been possible to compose a piyut with splitting in mind.

Why describe the whole avodah at Musaf, even the parts like the Temidim that by definition have to happen earlier and later?

And are (or were) there communities that split up the avodah similar to what I've described here?

Comment: This seems to assume the Piyut existed before its placement was determined. More likely is someone composed a Piyut for Musaf describing the Musaf Avoda and while he was at it he mentioned other parts of the day's service.

Comment: @DoubleAA but it would have been possible to compose a piyut that mentioned each part at its time.  See the first paragraph after the bullets.

Comment: You mean compose five Piyutim, one for each prayer? It certainly would be possible. But that wasn't his intention. There also could be a Piyut at every prayer ever describing the relavent Tamid or Musaf or burning things or time of day or position of the sun or whatever. This poet was writing a Piyut for Musaf about the unique Musaf Avoda.

Comment: @DoubleAA but it also mentions other things, special to Yom Kippur, that didn't happen at that time.  Like the whole preparation the week before.  And also the Kohen Gadol did everything (for some value of "everything") on Yom Kippur which means it's not just business as usual.  (And on top of that if I'm not mistaken some Rishonim say taking out the kaf and machta was after the tamid shel bein haarbayim, though אמיץ כח at least doesn't hold that way.)

Comment: Some things to consider - אמיץ כח isn't the only version around. It tends to be common for Nusach Ashkeanz and Sefard. Though, I think Yekkes have some variation to it. I don't know much about other Nuscha'ot. I can't say much about the mindset of the *paytan* for אמיץ כח  (was it Rav Luria?), but it's not uncommon to include "periphery". Compare Torah reading for Yom Tov. What does *Kol Habechor* have to do with Yom Tov? My opinion - personal bias b/c I'm ususally the Shachrit Shat"z. Shacharit is long enough. I really don't want it longer than it is. The Musaf Shat"z can have this job!

Comment: I feel like we're going in circles. I already acknowleged that.

Comment: Your idea is interesting. But, sometimes before getting to the main "instructions" you need to know the "introductory story" to it. If I tell you the intro one time and take a break and continue the story later, you would probably forget the first part and may not appreciate the "essence" that you read / hear later on. That, alone, may have been enough of a reason to place everything together.